JS redirect from [example.com/home] to [example.com/home?loc=USA] causes infinite loop
I'm trying to redirect from example.com/home to example.com/home?loc=USA.
But it causes infinite loop. How do I stop it? Thanks.
My code:
<script>
    window.location = "example.com/home?loc=USA";
</script>


Currently you're redirecting the user unconditionally, every time the page loads.  You can wrap that logic in a condition which checks if the query string parameter you're looking for exists or not.  For example:
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const loc = params.get('loc');
if (!loc) {
  window.location = "example.com/home?loc=USA";
}


Is it possible to redirect from /home to /home/USA using your code? Thanks.

@John: In that case you wouldn't be looking for a query string parameter but instead would be parsing the URL using whatever logic you'd want to define.  (e.g. Checking if the path is exactly /home)  But the concept is still the same.  If you want to redirect the user based on a specific condition, you define that condition in an if statement and redirect the user in that block.
